# SQL to delete the duplicates in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table transaction which has duplicates. i want to keep the record that had minimum id and delete all the duplicates based on four fields DATE, AMOUNT, REFNUMBER, PARENTFOLDERID. I wrote this query but i am not sure if this can be written in an efficient way. Do you think there is a better way? I am asking because i am worried about the run time.

```
DELETE FROM TRANSACTION
WHERE ID IN 
(SELECT FIT2.ID
FROM
(SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, FIT.DATE, FIT.AMOUNT, FIT.REFNUMBER, FIT.PARENTFOLDERID
FROM EWORK.TRANSACTION FIT
GROUP BY FIT.DATE, FIT.AMOUNT , FIT.REFNUMBER, FIT.PARENTFOLDERID
HAVING COUNT(1)>1 and FIT.AMOUNT >0) FIT1,
EWORK.TRANSACTION FIT2

WHERE FIT1.DATE=FIT2.DATE AND
FIT1.AMOUNT=FIT2.AMOUNT AND
FIT1.REFNUMBER=FIT2.REFNUMBER AND 
FIT1.PARENTFOLDERID=FIT2.PARENTFOLDERID AND 
FIT1.ID<>FIT2.ID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be more efficient to do something like

```
DELETE FROM transaction t1
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM transaction t2
                WHERE t1.date = t2.date
                  AND t1.refnumber = t2.refnumber
                  AND t1.parentFolderId = t2.parentFolderId
                  AND t2.id > t1.id )
```

Comment: Yes that works. I am not sure about the performance but it looks more legible.

Comment: @justin:I think using analytic function is much more optimized .what you say ?

Comment: @GauravSoni - I wouldn't expect it to be more efficient in this case.  With either my approach or yours, Oracle is going to have to hit the `transaction` table twice.  I would tend to expect that an anti-join would be a bit more efficient than the analytic function approach.  But it will depend on the indexes available, the data, how many duplicate rows there are, etc.  I wouldn't be shocked if in some cases the analytic function approach was a bit more efficient but I'd expect it to be reasonably close.

Comment: @JustinCave:you're correct,but in this case you're considering `id` as `primary key` .what if `id is not primary` .On what basis you'll do the join then.

Comment: @GauravSoni - The original poster requested that the row with the minimum `id` value be retained.  If you didn't care which row was retained, you could simply use the predicate `t2.rowid > t1.rowid`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM transaction
      WHERE ID IN (
               SELECT ID
                 FROM (SELECT ID,
                          ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY  date
                                                          ,amount
                                                          ,refnumber
                                                          ,parentfolderid
                                                ORDER BY ID) rn
                                              FROM transaction)
                WHERE rn <> 1);
```

I will try like this

Comment: @mahen:If the table is really really large,using the invaluable power of Analytics you can optimize

Comment: I believe you want to `ORDER BY id` in your analytic function.

Comment: @JustinCave:On you're suggestion ,i have edited my initial query .Thanks for you comments justin

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
DELETE transaction 
FROM transaction
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
       SELECT MIN(id) as id, date, amount, refnumber, parentfolderid 
       FROM transaction
      GROUP BY date, amount, refnumber, parentfolderid
   ) as validRows 
ON transaction.id = validRows.id
WHERE validRows.id IS NULL
```